# Display standard badges on website icon added on the home screen

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, homescreen, badge

My website is optimised to display an Icon and a custom app name when its added to home screen on iOS. Is it possible to display standard red number badge on this website icon, with javascript for exemple ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe of the icon is connected to a feed, possibly, but standard web apps, no.

Answer (score 2):

You can point iOS to an icon you want it to use for the bookmark, but you will not be able to change it later.  The recommended icon is 57x57.  You would not be able to draw a badge that extends outside your icon rect; but perhaps you could fake it by making a 50x50 icon with a "badge" in a 57x57 icon size.  Still it would never have the effect you want.

Read more about the "apple-touch-icon" in Apple's doc: [safari doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
```

Consider building a "Hybrid" application to point at your website.  Use QuickConnect or PhoneGap as a starting point; then you'll be able to use some "native app" methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know for thi Icon, it's already working, my quastion was more about having a badge and find a way tu update it with a feed.